# Dependency Injector. Inject a dependency into a route method from app.py

Tags: python, flask, dependency-injection

I have a small flask application that consists only from one `app.py` file. I'm using [python-dependency-injector](https://python-dependency-injector.ets-labs.org/) package. I want to inject a service into the `hello_world()` route method.

```
class MyService:
    def getMessage(self):
        return "Hello World!"


class Container(containers.DeclarativeContainer):
     my_service = providers.Factory(MyService)

    wiring_config = containers.WiringConfiguration(
        modules=[__name__],
    )

app = Flask(__name__)
container = Container()
app.run()

@app.route('/')
@inject
def hello_world(my_service: MyService = Provide[Container.my_service]):
    return my_service.getMessage()
```

For unknown reason, when `hello_world()` is executed, `my_service.getMessage()` fails because `my_service` is not an instance, but a provider object.

```
AttributeError: 'Provide' object has no attribute 'getMessage'
```

Probably I've missed something in the current setup. But I would like to receive `my_service` instance in `hello_word()`, so that I could call `my_service.getMessage()`